# How to replace an entire line of code in intellij , where lines start with a common prefix

Tags: intellij-idea, find-replace

i have a few lines of code like

```
line1
line2
//a comment line to be removed.
line3
//a comment line to be removed.
//a comment line to be removed
line4
```

here i will use find and input `//` so all the comment lines will be matched and highlighted.

now how do i repalce (remove) the entire line with the help of find and replace.

i.e what would be the replace text or regular expression.?

so the final output should be

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition to @Yumin, you can cover both below lines with this regular expression : (//.*)|(/\*.*?\*/)

1. //comment1
2. /*comment2*/

Answer (score 0):

In the find field, input "//.*\n" (exclude the ") as regular expression.
In the replace field, keep empty.
Click "Replace All" button. Done.